# MSVC complaining that function pointer is not a compile time constant

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I'm trying to get some code originally built with GCC to compile with MSVC, and am running into a problem with a callback wrapper class in the code. I've extracted the critical part of the code below:

```
template <typename T_func>
struct internal_parameter_resolver;

template <typename R>
struct internal_parameter_resolver<R()> {
    typedef R(*type)();
};

template <typename R, typename P1>
struct internal_parameter_resolver<R(P1)> {
    typedef R(*type)(P1);
};

template <typename T_func, typename internal_parameter_resolver<T_func>::type func>
void bind() {
    // Create and return instance of class Callback...
}

double func1() { return 0.5; }
int func2(double i) { return 0; }

int main() {
    bind<double(), &func1>();    // (Line 23)
    bind<int(double), &func2>(); // (Line 24)

    return 0;
}
```

While this compiles fine under GCC, MSVC 2010 gives the following error message:

```
1>c:\users\public\documents\projects\_test\_test\main.cpp(23): error C2975: 'func' : invalid template argument for 'bind', expected compile-time constant expression
1>          c:\users\public\documents\projects\_test\_test\main.cpp(14) : see declaration of 'func'
1>c:\users\public\documents\projects\_test\_test\main.cpp(24): error C2975: 'func' : invalid template argument for 'bind', expected compile-time constant expression
1>          c:\users\public\documents\projects\_test\_test\main.cpp(14) : see declaration of 'func'
```

Does anybody have an idea why MSVC thinks that those function pointers are not compile-time constants? Or is the problem elsewhere in the code (i.e., not lines 23 and 24)? If it's a bug in the compiler, I would welcome any suggestions as to a possible workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: Compiles fine using gcc 4.6 && clang 3.1.

Comment: @mfontanini Yes, I know, it's MSVC that's giving me problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
template <typename T_func, T_func* >
void bind() {
    // Create and return instance of class Callback...
}
```

Visual C++ is ungood at resolving indirect type definitions, but it's happy with more concrete types, like above.

The above shows what to do about the *direct problem* you have, with Visual C++.

However, a slightly better design would be to use automatic template argument deduction:

```
template <typename T_func >
void bind( T_func const func ) {
    // Create and return instance of class Callback...
}

double func1() { return 0.5; }
int func2(double i) { return 0; }

int main() {
    bind( func1 );      // (Line 23)
    bind( func2 );      // (Line 24)
}
```

You can obtain the function result type from `std::function`, if you want that, and so on.

Comment: Wow, it's really that simple (using T_func*)! Unfortunately I can't use automatic template argument deduction because instantiation of the callback class requires the function pointer as a template parameter. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to pass `func1` and `func2` as non-type template arguments.

It's better to just pass them as arguments(rather than template arguments), and let the `internal_parameter_resolver` trait deduce its type:

```
template <typename T_func>
struct internal_parameter_resolver;

template <typename R>
struct internal_parameter_resolver<R()> {
    typedef R(*type)();
};

template <typename R, typename P1>
struct internal_parameter_resolver<R(P1)> {
    typedef R(*type)(P1);
};

template <typename T_func>
void bind(typename internal_parameter_resolver<T_func>::type func) {
    // Create and return instance of class Callback...
}

double func1() { return 0.5; }
int func2(double i) { return 0; }

int main() {
    bind<double()>(func1);    // (Line 23)
    bind<int(double)>(func2); // (Line 24)

    return 0;
}
```

I don't have VC at hand, but that should compile.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately instantiation of the callback class requires the function pointer to be a template parameter (it's based on the lightweight callbacks described in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/136799/Lightweight-Generic-C-Callbacks-or-Yet-Another-Del ).